# Rounded Corners in IE: VML vs jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css, rounded-corners, vml

As a follow up to this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521432/best-jquery-rounded-corners-script

Assuming jQuery is already being included, what are the **tradeoffs** between the following IE solutions for rounded corners:

a) Using a VML solution for rounded corners (such as css3PIE, dd_roundies, and curved-corner)

b) Using a jQuery plugin (such as curvy corners, rounded corners, or jQuery.corner) to generate corner PNGs/GIFs?

Comment: One point - if you are bringing in jQuery to a page just to apply rounded corners you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Good point.  I made the assumption that jQuery was already included.  To make the question a bit more interesting I'm going to edit my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good (and stable) substitute for `border-radius`. VML has quite a few shortcomings which makes it render inappropriately or doesn't correctly apply in edge cases (of which there are two many).

My advice? Either listen to [this advice](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com) or stick to generating PNG/GIF rounded corners and applying them via conditional comments for IE.

Comment: OK, it seems using VML leads to certain positioning bugs as well as some issues with backgrounds.  Are there any issues with using jQuery for generated gifs that I should be aware/careful of?

Comment: All the same rules apply as if you would create the markup on the server beforehand.  See [this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customcorners2/), [this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/mountaintop/) and [this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/onionskin/) article on drop shadows and rounded borders.

Answer (score 1):

I tried them all, and as long as you just need rounded corners, you can't beat css3pie.
The drawbacks are so negligible that they're not even worth mentioning, unless you really have loads of them as it tends to slow down the page significantly.

Comment: I would say the downside to css3pie is its filesize, 31k (minified).  While it offers other CSS3 solutions for IE, it seems a bit overkill for just rounded corners.  I really wish it provided an option for a customized download.

Comment: @uglymunky gzip it and it should be around 10k. Still too much? Take a look at the project on github and build your own pie.htc with just rounded corners module.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do it through style sheets which will degrade okay:

```
.ui-corner-tl { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-top-left-radius: 4px; }
```

Comment: While technically, this would work, there are quite a lot of IE users out there and this would mean no rounded corners for any of them.  That would make me sad :(

Answer (score -3):

Best practice is to design for chrome, firefox and safari.  These are the most used browsers.

Comment: you just made that statistic up, didn't you?

Comment: No those stats are not made-up but are perfect, IE is falling.

Comment: 2011 Internet Explorer Firefox Chrome Safari Opera 
January 26.6 % 42.8% 23.8% 4.0% 2.5% 
source: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp so safari 4% to 26.6% IE still is a loss - only Firefox beats it. Jan 2011 stats.

Comment: i dont think that w3schools.com is a valid place for statistics, since its mostly visited by technical savy users and mostly the technical savy users are the one with the shiny browser, i think statistics should be gotten from sites which is used by normal joe like yahoo or facebook for example.